# Getting all reviews from a steam game using Steamworks?

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

Currently, I am trying to get all the steam reviews from a particular game, using the method described in the Steamworks documentation:
https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews

However, when I try to get reviews for a game like Team Fortress 2 for example using the method:
http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/440?json=1
I always get 20 reviews, due to the start_offset parameter.

Is there a way to get all the reviews in one method command, or do I have to create a loop with different start_offset?

Comment: `start_offset - reviews are returned in batches of 20, so pass 0 for the first set, then 20 for the next set, etc.`  Looks like you have to loop

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Steam changed the API and now `start_offset` is not working, they changed it to `cursor`.
here is more info:
https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews

in simple words: you send eg.
http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/10?json=1&cursor=*
and in return you get JSON with next cursor that you need to parse and use in next URL.

eg. `"cursor": "AoIIPwYYanDTv+QB"`

also you need to remember to encode cursor so next call would be like
http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/10?json=1&cursor=AoIIPwYYanDTv%2BQB

Comment: Hey fellas, thanks for your responses. I tried the above, which takes the resulting 'cursor' and joins it to your url example. It works, but I'm getting duplicates. Any ideas?(my code 
 -  https://pastebin.com/QiqzZnwR)

Comment: Check the doc for `filter`. Quoted below: `If paging through the reviews with cursor then choose either the recent option or the updated option to eventually receive an empty response list.`

Answer (score 1):

Taplar mentioned it correctly in his comment. `start_offset - reviews are returned in batches of 20, so pass 0 for the first set, then 20 for the next set, etc.` You need to use the offset like this:

- http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/10?json=1&start_offset=0
- http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/10?json=1&start_offset=20
- http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/10?json=1&start_offset=40

For a game like DOTA 2 there are like 650,000+ reviews. If you imagine yourself in Valve's place it would make sense to limit API calls. So I think it's safe to say that there is no API for all reviews at once.